# I see a warning notification "site not verified"

Tags: tls, chrome

Utill yesterday I never saw any warnings on secure sites like twitter and many others but currently I am getting an exclamation in my chrome saying identity not verified but https is indeed used, hence what to do in this situation?

following are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Well it was resolved today

Comment: Did you installed a new OS? Or somehow changed the system date in the BIOS

Comment: Please check your operating system date. It make similar trouble sometimes.

Comment: @TusharSharma no I did not

Answer (score 3):

Identity not verified means that the certificates being provided by the server are not able to be verified by Chrome.  Clicking on where the lock symbol would be should give you additional details about why it is failing.  Failure can result because the site's certificate is not signed by a root certificate you trust, it could be due to the certificate being revoked, it could result from your date being off and resulting in the certificate being outside the validity period for the certificate, etc.

Https will connect regardless of the presence of a valid certificate, but it means you have no idea who you are talking to.  It could be an attacker trying to compromise your connection unless the certificate resolves as valid and for the actual site you are trying to talk to.

Update: In this case, the certificate is unable to be audited.  In other words, it does not have the necessary information to be able to go to the CA and check if the certificate has been manually revoked prior to its expiration.  This is generally not a problem unless the site's private key may have been compromised.  It is possible something is blocking your ability to see certificate revocations or it may simply not be configured for that site.  It isn't ideal, but it is the least concerning reason for a certificate to be unable to validate.

Comment: see the update on question , neither seems to be the case

Comment: @AJ Henderson: Do you know what circumstances prompt a browser to say explicitly that a connection is unsafe ("Get me out of here!" on Chrome, etc.) vs. a more mild caution like the one seen in OP's case? Is it based on things like EFF's SSL Observatory or Google's Certificate Catalog, prompting a harsher warning for known/reported attackers, or are there certain criteria that were satisfied to yield OP's caution but whose omission would have caused a more extreme concern?

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshots, it seems that the problem is:

> Unable to check whether the certificate has been revoked.

[Theoretically](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6), a certificate (e.g. from a SSL server) may be accepted by some system (your Web browser) only if the certificate could be validated (a chain could be built, with all names and signatures OK, from a trusted root CA down to the certificate) *and* the "revocation status" of each certificate in the chain could be obtained with reasonable freshness. Revocation status of certificates is published by the CA through *Certificate Revocation List* and *OCSP*.

Here, Chrome is telling that it could not obtain fresh enough revocation information. So Chrome knows that the certificate *used to* be valid, but it cannot ascertain whether it is still valid *right now* (or at least that it was still valid not long ago). From Chrome's point of view, maybe the private key was stolen last month, and then the certificate was revoked: Chrome would not know; hence the warning.

Maybe the issuing CA failed to create the CRL in time; maybe some network glitch in your ISP blocks the download of the CRL. The URL from where the CRL is to be obtained can be found in the certificate extensions, in the "CRL Distribution Points" element. You could try to copy that CRL and try to get it with your browser directly, just to see if the download works at all; if it works, you can also see the `thisUpdate` and `nextUpdate` fields in that CRL: maybe it is old and out-of-date.

An additional complexity is that Windows tends to cache CRL, both positively and negatively. By "negative cache", I mean that if Windows tried to download a CRL from some URL (found in a certificate) and failed to find a valid CRL there (either the download failed, or the CRL was out-of-date), then it will not try again for several hours (apparently 8 hours or so). This caching behaviour that a temporary network glitch which breaks a CRL download can keep on impacting you for several hours. Try again tomorrow: maybe things will be back to good order then.

Comment: Thanks, but this problem is since yesterday and affects all ssl sites with same error. How can I ensure that there is no man in middle attack as I suspect one.

Answer (score 1):

First determine the cause of the problem. In your browser you can look at the certificate details for the secure sites you are accessing. This will allow you to look at the start/end date for the certificate (to verify it is still active) as well as the certificate chain (to verify that you are able to verify from the SSL cert through any intermediate issuer certs and up to the CA cert.

I would first suspect this last item to be failing. If you have installed a new browser, or perhaps somehow inadvertently removed all your local intermediate certs, then your browser may not be able to verify the issuer of the certs so it would then warn that the cert is not trusted.

As you have noted this does not mean the https connection will not succeed, but it does mean that you have no assurance you are actually connecting where you think you are.

Verify your cert stores, try different browsers (perhaps install a new one) and see if you can determine the reason for the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your hosts file if you have root access to your computer.  I spent a day troubleshooting this to find that the server I as trying to hit was being blocked in my hosts file.

Comment: but from the screenshots, you can see that he was able to reach the destination

Comment: He was able to reach Twitter, but the VeriSign server may have been blocked/redirected, thus the site is reachable, but not the CRL server.

Answer (score -2):

I came across this problem with "Chrome" and "Internet Explorer" and I managed to solve it by fully updating my Windows OS. Then try to search "youtube.com" and see if it works.